# How to make a form docked when the project is ran?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I'd like to make my form docked where it usually is when my application is executed.

I see only one way of doing that:
-Call OnDockDrop in the container where I usually drop it

But how to setup OnDockDrop's parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ManualDock method.

Answer (score 0):

yourForm.ManualDock(yourPanel, nil, alNone);